# Where can I ask about dojo interview questions?

Tags: support, on-topic-definition, questions

I'm going to attend a dojo interview by this week. But google doesn't help me to  find the list of dojo interview questions. I just wanted to know whether this site is a best place to ask interview questions, If not which stackexchange site is really intended for these kind of interview questions?

Comment: [Whiteboard - Programmers chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/the-whiteboard). Any programming related questions are welcome. One can go [full-blown crazy](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/conversation/gnat-goes-full-blown-crazy "example") there

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do interview questions make poor Software Engineering.SE questions?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6360/why-do-interview-questions-make-poor-software-engineering-se-questions)

Answer (score 2):

Asking for a list of dojo or any other kind of interview questions would be off-topic or closed as "too broad" as list questions don't really work well with the Stack Exchange format. That said, [the Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/) is a good place to ask more focused questions about interviewing and their [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3060/the-water-cooler) is a good place to ask more open-ended questions about interviewing.