# Can you please review the modifications for this question?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, closed-questions, specific-question, vote-to-reopen

I modified the original [Building a distributed system on Amazon Web Services](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/222222/building-a-distributed-system-on-amazon-web-services) after the comments mentioned about [Why do interview questions make poor Programmers.SE questions?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6360/why-do-interview-questions-make-poor-programmers-se-questions)

The question now is more focused about whether building an application on AWS makes it by default distributed.

Can you please re-open it?