# How should I tag interview related questions?

Tags: discussion, tags, clean-up

Apparently the interview tag is being removed, so how should I tag questions related to interviews?

*Edit*: To be clear, I am NOT asking about questions about questions that would be asked in an interview. I am asking about questions related to interviewing itself - for instance, something like "is it fair to ask an interviewee to do a coding exercise using a text editor they are unfamiliar with?" is not an "interview question" per se, but something about interviewing more generally, although still too programmer-focussed to fit on workplace.se. Granted, this specific example is probably too opinion-based to be a good fit for the site anyway, but I hope I've at least clarified the difference.

Comment: related: [Why do interview questions make poor Programmers.SE questions?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6361/31260)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of asking "How should I tag interview related questions?" You should probably be asking "Should I ask interview related questions?"

The general answer to *that* question is "No, you shouldn't be asking interview questions."  They're just a poor fit for the site.

Gnat linked a good reference question that goes into further detail.  [Why do interview questions make poor Programmers.SE questions?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6361/31260)  The TL;DR is we've tried them and they just don't work well on the site.

Comment: Ok, but then, where DO I ask interview related questions? There doesn't seem to be a site for it.

Comment: @Benubird Nowhere at Stack Exchange I'm afraid.
["We already tried supporting those questions, we even gave them their own site. Sadly, it didn't work out..."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200144/165773)

Comment: @gnat Wow, yeah, ok then. Thanks for giving me the link, I would not have found that myself.

Answer (score 3):

Is the question about the interview process itself or career advice in general?

**Yes:** do not ask here, it is off-topic. It *might* be appropriate at [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/), but you need to read their help center for guidance and compare against what you want to ask. You can always drop in their chat or ask on their meta to be sure first.

**No:** remove language relevant to the interview. Congratulations! You have a question useful for your immediate need while also being applicable to other programmers, whether they are interviewing or not.

Example: if you want feedback on a whiteboard-type question asked during an interview, leave out the interview part and try to keep it in scope to avoid it being closed as too broad.

Also be sure to [read the link that gnat posted](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6361/31260).